# nested forEach loops - error "forEach is not a function"

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach

I had a simple for each, but realised I needed to get a different property of my JSON, so I need now to have 2 nested `forEach` loops, but I am not sure how to do this properly. I am getting an error saying my second `forEach` is not a function.

I had this code first:

```
getExample.then(function(response) {
  response.data.forEach(function(x) {
    x.friendlyName = x.AccountTransferFinalityCategoryName + "-" + x.AccountTransferFinalityName;
  });
});
```

than I tried to change it to this:

```
response.data.forEach(function (x) {
  x.accounttransferfinalitycategory.forEach(function (y) {
    x.friendlyName = x.accounttransferfinalitycategory[y].AccountTransferFinalityCategoryName + "-" + x.AccountTransferFinalityName;
  });
});
```

But I get an error now, what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Probably *x.accounttransferfinalitycategory* is not an array!!!

Comment: please provide sample response data

Comment: Is it `x.AccountTransferFinalityCategoryName` or `x.accounttransferfinalitycategoryname` ? That really matters ...

Comment: we definitely need to see what the data is - but most likely `x.accounttransferfinalitycategory` is `undefined`, either because the response isn't what you expect, or you mis-spelled the property name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to say , but i think your problem is with applying `forEach` to object,
be sure that `x.accounttransferfinalitycategory` is array , if it is object try below code

```
x =  x.accounttransferfinalitycategory;
Object.keys(x).forEach(function (key){
    console.log(x[key]);
});
```

or update your question with response and expected output :-)

Answer (score -5):

I think you need this

### $.each(result, function () { console.log(this.Id); console.log(this.Value); });